# Does this program successfully work?

Tags: c

I was just wondering if I correctly formatted this program in order to do what was being asked of me...

Here's the problem: The counting algorithm shown above forms the basis for a simple and efficient sorting algorithm. Given a set of positive integers, we can construct a table of how many times each of the integers appears and then use the count information to print a list of the integers in order from smallest to largest.

Use this approach to construct a program that opens a file containing a list of positive integers, sorts the integers, and writes them back out to a second file. You may assume that none of the integers is larger than 100000.

The counting algorithm was given as:

```
void gatherCounts(int A[], int N, int counts[]) {
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        counts[n] = 0;
    for(n = 0; n < N; n++)
        counts[A[n] - 1]++;
}
```

That is for a set of numbers no larger than 10, so my attempt at solving the problem was:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gatherCounts(int A[], int N, int counts[]) {
    FILE *input;
    int n;
    input = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    while(!feof(input)) {
        for(n = 0; n < 100000; n++)
            counts[n] = 0; 
        for(n = 0; n < N; n++)
            counts[A[n] - 1]++;
    }
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

This should read a file named "numbers" sort the integers within the file and write them back on a second file. Please let me know if this is correct and where, if there are any, my issues lie. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the entire code, including the `main()`?

Comment: Don’t you think you should at some point actually read something from the input file and at some point create some output? I mean, you did try running the program and saw it doesn’t work (and does not even ever terminate), right?

Comment: Well, does it output what you expect?

Comment: At no time do you read anything from the file, so the `while(!feof(input)) {...}` will loop forever because the file pointer will remain at the beginning of the file. When you *do* add code to read from the file, if it is a text file, you will have to convert the text (*C* strings) into integers. A̶l̶s̶o̶,̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶v̶e̶n̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶l̶ ̶*̶C̶*̶ ̶s̶t̶y̶l̶e̶s̶.̶(fixed)

Comment: The usual flow diagram on writing a program is: 1. write something; 2. does it work as it's supposed to? 2a. no -> go to 1; 2b. Yes -> exit (SUCCES); You seem to be stuck on 1.

Comment: Did you test this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @user3408753 You should show how you tried to solve your problem yourself, and where you got stuck, then people will help you overcome *that* difficulty

Answer (score 1):

The function given totals the number of each integer in an array. The offset of each total is the number being counted. It's a simple matter of feeding it an input, length, and output:

```
int main(void) {
    int A[] = {8, 4, 6, 8, 1, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9};
    int N = 10;
    int counts[10];
    int n0, n1;
    memset(counts, 0, 10);
    gatherCounts(A, N, counts);
    for (n0 = 0; n0 < N; n0++) {
        for (n1 = 0; n1 < counts[n0]; n1++)
            printf("%d ", n0 + 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure to do more research, and of course test your code using output before asking any more questions like this.